# Unable to run paper.js from .html file

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

Dear all I didn't find a normal explanation so I decided to ask for your help.
I want to create a paper.js project in html file. The problem that I cannot connect them I tried to use  `var scope = new paper.PaperScope();
                scope.setup(myCanvas);`

But it didn't work out.
 Here is the code taken from  [Paper.js web site](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/interaction/creating-mouse-tools/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper.js"></script>
<!-- Define inlined JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Only executed our code once the DOM is ready.
var scope = new paper.PaperScope();
scope.setup(myCanvas);

var myPath = new Path();
myPath.strokeColor = 'black';

// This function is called whenever the user
// clicks the mouse in the view:
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // Add a segment to the path at the position of the mouse:
    myPath.add(event.point);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't do anything here...
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the file `paper.js` in the same folder as your html file.

Comment: When writing in JavaScript, everything is a property of the paper object -> Use `new paper.Path()` instead of `new Path()`

Comment: Both files are in the same folder, and I did used the paper.Path right now, still nothing... But thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this tutorial: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/


Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Define inlined JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Only executed our code once the DOM is ready.
        window.onload = function() {
            // Get a reference to the canvas object
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            // Create an empty project and a view for the canvas:
            paper.setup(canvas);

            var myPath = new paper.Path();
            myPath.strokeColor = 'black';

            // Draw the view now:
            paper.view.draw();

            var tool = new paper.Tool();

            tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
                myPath.add(event.point);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ooh man :) The app is ready for a weeks already :) But thanks anyway. I appreciate that